# Clearcase on windows is very slow as compare to the clearcase on Unix?

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

Our windows cleacase is getting very slow and it takes more than one hour to get down to the user's stream and to create a view. In what way we can boost the speed of clearcase windows? we have tried to make the unused stream to "obsolete" but it didn't work so well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Obsoleting streams won't change anything: ClearCase would still have to manage the same number of UCM object (it might only increase the display of projects in the ClearCase project explorer).

Various reasons can explain performance issues on Windows/ClearCase, depending on the version of Windows and of ClearCase:

- registry issue ([`MiniFilterMask` key](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21450326))
- [license caching](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21431836)
- [Network provided order](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21135684)

One way of detecting performance issue is by using the [Rational ClearCase Reports](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m2/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_proj.doc/c_reports_use.htm) (Windows only), which can help keep track of the performance of commands/scripts you would execute on a regular basis.

You can also mitigate the performance issue by setting up *another* Vob server/View server (with its own registry server) in order to register a subset of the same vobs, and see if the speed improves then: make sure those servers are on the same box than the vobs they are referring to, in order to register only vobs with a local path (and not a network parh, which can be slower to access).

Comment: Do you think the clearcase bugs will make the windows clearcase slow? if so, what are the symptoms?

Comment: @user2370590 what "ClearCase bugs" are you referring to?

Comment: I have not seen any crashes but the problem is it is very slow. Through WAN it is almost impossible to work so wondering any fix patches to boost the speed in clearcase 7.1.2.6.

Comment: @user2370590 An update of the server and client can speed things up a bit. But for a WAN, I generally used CCRC (ClearCase Remote Client) rather than ClearCase. That solution (remote client) has been generalized with CC 8.x and its ClearTeam Explorer.

Comment: do you know what repository is required to install CCRC in windows? Currently my cclient ver is 7.1.2.10? I mapped the network drive and I just need to know which file to add as preference and install for CCRC?

Comment: @user2370590 If you have 'cleartool', that means you have a full ClearCase client. CCRC is completely independent, and doesn't depend on a "map drive" or a "preference file". See https://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m0/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ms_install.doc/topics/c_inst_ccrc.htm.

Comment: how do I find the differences between CCRC and clearcase cc? How do I know if it is working? Is there a way to check it?

Comment: @user2370590 yes: simply check if you have cleartool.exe, and that mmeans you have a full ClearCase and not CCRC. As for the difference between the two: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21233090

Comment: i checked ccrc.exe..it is there but how do i connect this to my existing clearcase, to make a view/stream?

Comment: @user2370590 that would be http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21205629: you must have a CCRC client to connect to a CCRC server.

Comment: I want to do this because my cc client is very slow. matter a fact I didn't realize that ccrc will be slower because cc client is slow and is limited to snapshot only. I upgraded my cc client but still doesn't see any good performance.

Comment: @user2370590 if your cc client isn't a ccrc client, it should support dynamic views as well, no?

Comment: It says only snapshot and I haven't seen any ccrc supporting dymanic. http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/09/continuousintegrationrationalclearcaseremoteclient/ but my problem was checking out/in dynamic, it is taking too long. Do you know how to trace system once the  cleartool co command is executed?

Comment: @user2370590 if it is a checkout with ccrc, an admin should check the ccrc server (websphere), and then checkout the same file in a full ClearCase view on the server, to check that is is quicker there: that would help pinpoint the issue, which can be on the CCRC server itself, or in the LAN route between the client and the server.